# What happens after you call document.getElementById() in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to refresh some div in my website dynamically.

```
 //code changing the source
 document.getElementById('#chatbox').src = document.getElementById('#chatbox').src;   //refreshes the chatbox
 alert("HERE");
```

The alert() function does not get executed after getElementbyId() is called. 
What is going on?

Comment: that's your entire javascript code?

Comment: Nothing special happens, [it works fine](http://jsbin.com/edafib/1/edit).

Comment: anyway from the looks of your code, the `alert` function will call even if the `getElementById` fails... correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @RenoYeo — You're wrong. If the gEBI fails, then it will return `null`, and trying to access the `src` property of `null` will throw a TypeError exception.

Comment: ah, I see. hey look, a squirrel!

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access `src` of undefined as there is probably no element with the id "#chatbox".

Remove the hash and it should work:

```
document.getElementById('chatbox').src
```

To debug take a look at your javascript error console or try

```
alert(document.getElementById('#chatbox')) // undefined
```

Comment: Thanks that did work! What if I wanted to get the class of the element, getElementByClass()?

Comment: @user `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: You can use `document.querySelector()`

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('chatbox').src`?

Comment: Start a new question or try google ;) `document.getElementById('chatbox').className`

Answer (score 0):

That's because it should be

```
document.getElementById('chatbox')
```

Perhaps you are confusing this with jQuery. With jQuery, you would use:

```
$('#chatbox')
```

Comment: Maybe. The question didn't include the HTML, so we don't know what the ID really is. It might have a # in it.

Comment: @Quentin Nevertheless that would be very odd, and I think it's a safe assumption that the ID has no hash.